# Finding proportions using the Empirical Rule.

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

Can someone please help me understand this question?

> A population data set with a bell-shaped distribution has mean $\mu = 2$ and standard deviation $\sigma = 1.1$. Find the approximate proportion of observations in the data set that lie above $3.1$.

Since the curve is bell-shaped, I would think the Empirical Rule can be used. However, I don't know where to begin since I am not given a closed interval...

My guess is that, since $3.1 = 2 + (1)(1.1) = \mu + (1)\sigma$, $3.1$ is the left endpoint for the $68\%$ of data that lie within one standard deviation of the mean. The textbook answer is $0.16$, so clearly my guess is very wrong!

Comment: Hint: how much data is further than one standard deviation away?

Comment: @SeanRoberson $32\%$? Then $16\%$ of data after that endpoint....I think I got it now!! Thanks for the tip. :)!!